# execute program in php

Tags: php, apache, mobile, lamp

Is there a way to execute a program on the server, Example: Firefox, Gimp, Etc.

My concept is to be able to log into my local LAMP server on my phone, type in a command on a text box (eg: /usr/bin/firefox) and press a button which sends the command string using the post method to another PHP script that starts the program on my server. This would be good so when I'm on the road and want to start "firefox http://www.blahblah.net" and come back to my computer with firefox opened up. Yes, I am aware of the security issues but it is just a proof-of-concept.

I've tried the exec() and system() commands but they don't seem to work.... Am I doing something wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

disable :protection # not needed on something this simple
set :port, 11111    # think 1APPX

get '/' do
# this handles both apps (via ?app=...) and files (via ?file=...)

if params[:app] then
    # as a side effect, this also happens to actually run the app, which is
    # pretty much what we wanted in the first place
    @fn = params[:app][1..-2];
    `/usr/bin/env #{@fn}`
elsif params[:file] then
    # bugfix, remove quotes...
    @fn = params[:file][1..-2];
    # xdg-open anyone?
    puts "DEBUG /usr/bin/env xdg-open #{@fn}";
    `"/usr/bin/env xdg-open #{@fn}"`
else
    # nothing...
    404
end

end

not_found do
status 404
"Application #{@fn} not found. Usage: /?app=\"[appname]\" or /?file=\"[filename]\""
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a web application for this. The security hurdles are many, and would require extensive knowledge of Linux systems administration to make this happen.

My advice is to get an SSH client for your phone - they exist for Android and iOS, and connect to your computer via SSH.  You can also get VNC clients for both those platforms so that you could operate directly on the GUI without having to trick X11 into launching applications on a display you're not actually viewing.

Comment: Probably the best idea.... The only thing is it is a console.... What I really did was parse the desktop files in /usr/share/applications and show their icons on the webpage and when the icons are pressed they execute the file they correspond to.

Comment: @user1427152 No idea how Jolicloud executes, but I'm guessing it isn't with basic PHP. Probably a socket between their web front end and a custom display server.

Answer (score 2):

In first place, you should running your apache server with the user which will be log. Next, you should to execute:

```
<?php
system("export DISPLAY=:0; /usr/bin/firefox;");
```

I tested here and worked

Answer (score 1):

I would look into writing a "userland" daemon that runs in the system tray listening for HTTP (or HTTPS) requests and opens the appropriate program instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the full path

```
exec('/full/path/to/firefox http://google.com');
```

Comment: How's this going to launch a web browser from a process spawned by the web server that opens up on the user's desktop?

Comment: @Michael I think the OP wants to do this in his desktop/local LAMP.

Comment: ls just dumps output to stdout. executing firefox from a webserver won't - apache won't have any rights to run a program in the X server, and firefox would in any case be started up using the webserver's userid, which will NOT be of any use.